# Delay before getRedirectResult called after user back from auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We're authenticating our users with delegated Twitter auth. This has been working perfectly using `.signInWithPopup`. After switching to `.signInWithRedirect` we're noticing a second+ delay between the moment the user returns to the callback page in our app and `.getRedirectResult().then()` being called. Can this be mitigated somehow? Also, can we even discern between sign-ups and sign-ins right after redirect? Thank you!

Comment: Help, Firebase Team! I think this is an easy fix, as you have solved it with firebase-ui already – cf. comment below

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing delays, you could show a spinner before that promise resolves. There are a bunch of things that happen in the background and may need some time to resolve especially as the rest of the page resources are downloaded and rendered.

`getRedirectResult` returns a `firebase.auth.UserCredential` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential) which exposes an `isNewUser` flag to differentiate new/existing users: `https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#.AdditionalUserInfo`

Comment: Necrothread, beware. Still very much an open issue! The problem is that getRedirectResult is only about 2 seconds after the redirect happened. Our users are presented with the same sign in view again and wonder what's going on. So we need a way to tell if the authentication is pending. I can see an iframe being loaded into DOM by Firebase. That is our only indicator for a pending authentication.

Google came up with what we need with the `.isPendingRedirect` method here https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web, but I have a hard time debugging how they do it exactly.

Comment: Such an important question. Any way to handle other than isPendingRedirect ?